# Disable gzip HTTP compression to prevent Breach attack

Tags: java, spring, security, gzip

I have created a Restful API in Spring-Java, and now I need to disable gzip HTTP compression to prevent the Breach attack.  I don't know how to implement this, please, can anybody help me with this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is something to configure at your http server level, not in your application. Some examples would be to set compression="off" in your Tomcat SSL connector, or set gzip off; in your Nginx frontend, etc.